# Laravel syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have upload my files to a new server and error occurres in this line

```
   if(empty($data['customer_id'])) -- Error in thisline
```

with message `syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)`

the data is comming from

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    if(empty($data['customer_id']))
        $data['customer_id'] = Customer::create($data)->id;
```

If I change it to $data->customer_id it is not throwing error

Comment: What do you get if you run ```dd($request->all())``` ?, Let we know

Comment: It is parse error

Comment: Change ```empty()``` method to ```isset()```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: @ADyson No it does not slove my problem

Comment: This bit specifically I was thinking of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them/18092288#18092288

Comment: It must be said though, that the code you've shown in the question does not, by itself, cause this syntax error. Are certain that's a) the correct bit of the code, and b) the correct version of the code?

Comment: I changed to isset() it show same error. If I change it to $data->customer_id it is not throwing error

Comment: Try with double quote `$data["customer_id"]`

Comment: I tried with double quote $data["customer_id"] no change in the response it is again showing the error message